# What SELECT instruction lowers to in ISA?

Tags: llvm, vectorization, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

While vectorizing if the loop contains 'if constructs' llvm tries to flatten them by replacing with SELECT instructions to make the control flow straight, if the basic blocks cannot be turned to predicated instructions like SELECT, llvm can't vectorize it. Till now am assuming that there should be some equivalent instruction for SELECT like IR instructions. I searched for predicated instruction in intel architecture I din't got any. Can someone please tell me does current ISA architectures support predicated instructions? If not, How the SELECT instructions will be lowered into machine instructions? Please correct me if I have made any wrong assumptions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The select instructions is lowered through a custom lowering or pseudo instructions. Checkout MSP430ISelLowering.cpp for more info

Comment: There is no one-to-one ISA instruction for select, as a select node is lowered into phi nodes and basic blocks

Comment: Your second comment is little confusing, why  select node is lowered into phi nodes and basic blocks. Can you please give me pointer for this.

Comment: a select node is generate for example for a ternary operation. As such operations are basically "if conditions", they are basically lowered into conditional structures; hence we have a phi node and a two basic blocks for true and false conditions.

Comment: What you said is partially true "a select node is generated for a ternary operation", in addition while vectorizing the loops compilers flattens the "if constructs" all the instruction in "if body" and "else body" will be converted to select statements. They are not again lowered to conditional structures.

Comment: This is incorrect: select can be turned into conditional move for instance.
Note also that some architectures (GPU come to my mind) have native select in their ISA, sometimes taking 4 operands (two for doing the conditional, and 2 for the possible results).

Answer (score 1):

Yes several architectures support conditional/predicated execution. For example ARM has csel [AArch64 ISA](https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/41836-102-1-229511/ARM.Reference_Manual.pdf).

It is quite common in VLIW architectures because they need to fill the packets.
[Predicated execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predication_(computer_architecture))